# Laravel 5.5 password reset success custom param not being passed through

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created my own view that shows once password has successfully been reset.

I am trying to pass the user's email to this view so I modified the `ResetPasswords` trait that handles the redirect:

```
protected function sendResetResponse($response, $request)
    {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath())
                            ->with('status', trans($response))->with('email', $request->email);
    }
```

This should pass the value to the view, my view file (`reset-success.blade.php`):

```
@extends('quarx-frontend::layout.master')

@section('content')

<div class="row raw-margin-top-72 text-center">

        <h1 class="text-center">Password successfully changed!</h1>

        {{ $email  }}

</div>

@stop
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Undefined variable: email (View:
>   C:\wamp\www\a-api\resources\views\auth\passwords\reset-success.blade.php)

Comment: Did you override the sendResetResponse in your ResetPasswordController?

Comment: Do you not need to also specify the type of variable... IE post or get? It's been a while since I last laraveled but I'm thinking something like `$request->input('email')`

Comment: @Troyer I didn't override it but changed it directly to this `$this->sendResetResponse($response, $request)`

Comment: @Dale I don't need to do that in here, if I do `dd($request->email);` inside the `sendResetResponse` function I do get the email coming through.

Comment: @user3574492 ah right, like I said been a while :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are overriding the trait directly, that's not correct, you should override it in your `app/http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php` controller; If you modify it directly on the vendor folder, next time you do a composer update/install it will **go away**.

Just copy your code there and it should work:

```
protected function sendResetResponse($response, $request){
  return redirect($this->redirectPath())
       ->with(['email => $request->email, 'status' => trans($response)]);
}
```

Then your changes are safe from composer install/update.

Comment: How about the `reset()` method in the `ResetsPasswords` trait. I also changed that directly: `$this->sendResetResponse($response, $request)`?

Comment: Everything you modify inside the vendor folder will go away when installing/updating composer, you need to override it in your Laravel app.

Comment: I'm still getting `Undefined variable: email` after placing all that code in my `ResetPasswordController`

Comment: The `sendResetResponse` is getting the request variable fine but just not passing it to the view.

Comment: @user3574492 try to send the data as array in one with()

Comment: That does the exact same thing. Chaining the with statements is exactly the same as this.